# RAML validation throws 'Invalid value type'

Tags: maven, yaml, raml, raml-java-parser

I try to validate [linkedin.raml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mulesoft/api-console/master/dist/examples/linkedin.raml) but I got below set of validation errors for some reason.

```
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,776] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  Invalid value type
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,778]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  schema can not be empty
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,778] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  invalid JSON schema: no JSON Text to read from input
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,778]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  example can not be empty
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,778]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  schema can not be empty
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,778] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  invalid JSON schema: no JSON Text to read from input
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,778]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  example can not be empty
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,778]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  schema can not be empty
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,778] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  invalid JSON schema: no JSON Text to read from input
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,778]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  example can not be empty
[2015-10-07 00:09:46,778]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.registry.custom.extensions.handlers.utils.RAMLProcessor} -  schema can not be empty
...
```

Below is the code snippet I used to validate RAML

```
private boolean isValidRAML(String sourceUrl) {
        boolean isNoError = true;

        List<ValidationResult> results = RamlValidationService.createDefault().validate(sourceUrl);
        Iterator<ValidationResult> resultsIterator = results.iterator();
        while (resultsIterator.hasNext()) {
            ValidationResult valResult = resultsIterator.next();
            String resultLevel = valResult.getLevel().toString();
            String resultMessage = valResult.getMessage();
            if (CommonConstantsRAML.ERROR_PARAMETER_NAME.equals(resultLevel)) {
                log.error(resultMessage);
                isNoError = false;
            } else if (CommonConstantsRAML.WARN_PARAMETER_NAME.equals(resultLevel)) {
                log.warn(resultMessage);
            }
        }

        return isNoError;
    }
```

Is this expected? if not what is causing this? for more reference kindly find set of mvn dependancies I have used in my orbit bundle.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.raml</groupId>
            <artifactId>raml-parser</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.11</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>  
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.logging</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

[image]

Apparently in the [linkedin.raml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mulesoft/api-console/master/dist/examples/linkedin.raml) at line number :178 causing this issue. Why is this?

```
175:settings:
176:        authorizationUri: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization
177:        accessTokenUri: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken
178:        authorizationGrants: code
```

Comment: Not sure this RAML is valid: there are many places where the JSON schema property is defined but is left empty. Can you do a find/replace to get rid of the empty `schema: |` properties and see if you can validate after this change?

Comment: But when I upload this to https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/apiplatform it do not show any errors.

Comment: Maybe a different parser is used over there? In any case, did you try what I suggested? That would help us narrow down the issue.

Comment: Now I cant see the 'invalid JSON schema: no JSON Text to read from input' error message. The only error that i'm seen is 'Invalid value type'. Please find the attached screenshot in the end of the question.

Comment: `authorizationGrants` should be a list: `authorizationGrants: [code]` See spec: https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/raml-0.8.md#oauth-20

Comment: Yup, it worked when I change it to list.
authorizationGrants: [code]
Thanks

Comment: Excellent: I've summarized this discussion in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RAML you're using is unfortunately littered with error. It may correspond to an old version of the spec?

Anyways, to fix the issues:

- Find/replace to get rid of the empty `schema: |` properties,
- Fix `authorizationGrants` so it becomes a list: `authorizationGrants: [code]`